# E/SchoolService: Unable to resolve host "schoolmanager": No address associated with hostname

Tags: android-studio, retrofit, samsung

Estoy desplegando, en un dispositivo físico ("Samsung S7"), una app desarrollada en "Android Studio", pero a la hora de hacer peticiones con "Retrofit2" al servidor donde está la "API" me muestra el siguiente mensaje de error:
E/SchoolService: Unable to resolve host "schoolmanager": No address associated with hostname

El "ApiService" sería el siguiente:

```
public interface ApiService {
    @GET("school")
    Call<List<School>> getSchoolsCall();

    @GET("school/{id}")
    Call<School> getSchoolCall(@Field("id") Integer id);
}
```

El cliente de "Retrofit" sería el siguiente:

```
public class RetrofitClient {
    public static final String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
    private static final String REMOTE_URL = "http://SchoolManager:8080/api/";
    private static Retrofit retrofitInstance;

    private static String token;
    private static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private static LegalGuardianRepository legalGuardianRepository;

    public static Retrofit getRetrofitClient() {
        if (retrofitInstance == null) {
            OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().build();

            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT).create();

            retrofitInstance = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(REMOTE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build();
        }

        return retrofitInstance;
    }

    public static ApiService getApiService(Application application) {
        if (sharedPreferences == null) {
            sharedPreferences =
           PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(application.getApplicationContext());
        }

        Retrofit retrofit = getRetrofitClient();

        return retrofit.create(ApiService.class);
    }
}
```

Al realizar una petición con "Check Proxy Settings" de "Android Studio":

[image: Check Proxy Settings]

Vemos que el resultado es el esperado:

[image: Resultado de la petición]

La configuración que le he dado al proxy es:

[image: Configuración Proxy]

¿Alguien sabría decirme que estoy haciendo mal?
¿Podría ser que tenga que hacer alguna configuración en el dispositivo físico de pruebas para que reconozca el "HostName"?